# Unity: Unable to convert classes into dex format Plugins: Unity IAP 1.16 Facebook SDK 7.13.0

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-sdk-tools, dex

got a problem with Facebook SDK. When i installed this i got error: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
There are installed plagins: Unity IAP 1.16, Facebook SDK 7.13.0, Google Play Service 0.9.50, Appodeal 2.8.45.
Unity 2017.1.2p3.
jdk1.8.0_181 and latest version of sdk tools
No same files or files with diffrent version there.
[Here is the link for pastebin with error](https://pastebin.com/PMwnYV9B)

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Android\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[

trouble writing output: Too many field references to fit in one dex file: 86260; max is 65536.
You may try using multi-dex. If multi-dex is enabled then the list of classes for the main dex list is too large.
References by package:
 3 android.accounts
30 android.app
 1 android.bluetooth
 2 android.content
60 android.content.pm
10 android.content.res
 3 android.database
49 android.graphics
 2 android.graphics.drawable
 4 android.hardware
 2 android.media
 1 android.media.browse
 4 android.net
 6 android.net.wifi
28 android.os
 3 android.print
 4 android.provider
13 android.support.annotation
  1546 android.support.compat
  1546 android.support.coreui
  1546 android.support.coreutils
  1648 android.support.customtabs
  1546 android.support.fragment
  1705 android.support.graphics.drawable
  1546 android.support.graphics.drawable.animated
  1546 android.support.mediacompat
  1546 android.support.v4
13 android.support.v4.accessibilityservice
17 android.support.v4.animation
   885 android.support.v4.app
   114 android.support.v4.content
     1 android.support.v4.content.pm
     1 android.support.v4.content.res
11 android.support.v4.graphics
41 android.support.v4.graphics.drawable
 4 android.support.v4.hardware.display
12 android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint
10 android.support.v4.internal.view
   388 android.support.v4.media
   379 android.support.v4.media.session
10 android.support.v4.net
19 android.support.v4.os
63 android.support.v4.print
10 android.support.v4.provider
55 android.support.v4.text
 6 android.support.v4.text.util
   118 android.support.v4.util
   434 android.support.v4.view
   138 android.support.v4.view.accessibility
 8 android.support.v4.view.animation
   495 android.support.v4.widget
   409 android.support.v7.app
  1546 android.support.v7.appcompat
  1546 android.support.v7.cardview
 8 android.support.v7.content.res
18 android.support.v7.graphics.drawable
 1 android.support.v7.text
 2 android.support.v7.transition
77 android.support.v7.view
   249 android.support.v7.view.menu
   856 android.support.v7.widget
 6 android.text
 1 android.text.util
16 android.util
22 android.view
 8 android.view.accessibility
 3 android.webkit
23 android.widget
 2 bitter.jnibridge
   158 bolts
  1540 com.CODvinn.GameOfWords
  1540 com.adcolony.adcolonysdk
  1270 com.adcolony.sdk
  1616 com.amazon.device.ads
  1560 com.android.vending.billing
 4 com.applovin.sdk
  1037 com.appodeal.ads
   128 com.appodeal.ads.a
   129 com.appodeal.ads.b
80 com.appodeal.ads.c
98 com.appodeal.ads.d
   174 com.appodeal.ads.e
58 com.appodeal.ads.f
   146 com.appodeal.ads.g
   150 com.appodeal.ads.native_ad
   107 com.appodeal.ads.native_ad.views
49 com.appodeal.ads.networks
68 com.appodeal.ads.networks.a
45 com.appodeal.ads.networks.vpaid
   177 com.appodeal.ads.utils
19 com.appodeal.ads.utils.a
47 com.appodeal.ads.utils.b
 4 com.appodeal.ads.utils.c
  1540 com.appodeal.appodeal.unity
  1540 com.appodeal.inmobi.unity
  1540 com.appodeal.ogury.unity
 1 com.appodeal.sdk
  1540 com.appodeal.startapp.unity
37 com.appodeal.unity
  1540 com.appodeal.yandexmetrica.unity
31 com.appodealx.applovin
28 com.appodealx.mraid
66 com.appodealx.sdk
17 com.appodealx.vast
 2 com.chartboost.sdk.Libraries
   180 com.evernote.android.job
 5 com.evernote.android.job.gcm
10 com.evernote.android.job.util
16 com.evernote.android.job.util.support
16 com.evernote.android.job.v14
 2 com.evernote.android.job.v19
12 com.evernote.android.job.v21
 3 com.evernote.android.job.v24
 2 com.evernote.android.job.v26
 3 com.facebook.ads
  1540 com.google.android.gms
20 com.google.android.gms.actions
 4 com.google.android.gms.ads
21 com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier
  1594 com.google.android.gms.auth
 5 com.google.android.gms.auth.account
  1563 com.google.android.gms.auth.api
68 com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer
97 com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials
 6 com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone
  1540 com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.license
37 com.google.android.gms.auth.api.proxy
59 com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin
34 com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal
  1540 com.google.android.gms.auth.license
  1540 com.google.android.gms.base
  1540 com.google.android.gms.base.license
   102 com.google.android.gms.common
98 com.google.android.gms.common.api
   338 com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal
41 com.google.android.gms.common.data
44 com.google.android.gms.common.images
   160 com.google.android.gms.common.internal
  1540 com.google.android.gms.common.license
35 com.google.android.gms.common.stats
27 com.google.android.gms.common.util
  1688 com.google.android.gms.drive
54 com.google.android.gms.drive.events
  1540 com.google.android.gms.drive.license
10 com.google.android.gms.drive.metadata
20 com.google.android.gms.drive.metadata.internal
39 com.google.android.gms.drive.query
49 com.google.android.gms.drive.query.internal
 8 com.google.android.gms.drive.widget
25 com.google.android.gms.dynamic
20 com.google.android.gms.dynamite
 2 com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.flags
16 com.google.android.gms.flags.impl
  1915 com.google.android.gms.games
25 com.google.android.gms.games.achievement
13 com.google.android.gms.games.event
   155 com.google.android.gms.games.internal
   128 com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api
12 com.google.android.gms.games.internal.experience
46 com.google.android.gms.games.internal.player
61 com.google.android.gms.games.leaderboard
  1540 com.google.android.gms.games.license
61 com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer
50 com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime
49 com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.turnbased
56 com.google.android.gms.games.quest
34 com.google.android.gms.games.request
46 com.google.android.gms.games.snapshot
15 com.google.android.gms.games.stats
40 com.google.android.gms.games.video
 3 com.google.android.gms.iid
  1518 com.google.android.gms.internal
 5 com.google.android.gms.location.places
  1547 com.google.android.gms.nearby
72 com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection
  1540 com.google.android.gms.nearby.license
95 com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages
 2 com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.audio
   163 com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.internal
 6 com.google.android.gms.security
  1588 com.google.android.gms.tasks
  1540 com.google.android.gms.tasks.license
  1540 com.google.example.games.mainlibproj
  1581 com.google.games.bridge
15 com.inmobi.a
  1076 com.inmobi.ads
70 com.inmobi.ads.cache
 7 com.inmobi.commons.a
39 com.inmobi.commons.core.a
24 com.inmobi.commons.core.b
13 com.inmobi.commons.core.c
62 com.inmobi.commons.core.configs
10 com.inmobi.commons.core.d
43 com.inmobi.commons.core.e
12 com.inmobi.commons.core.f
66 com.inmobi.commons.core.network
29 com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities
 6 com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.a
37 com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.b
10 com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.uid
   160 com.inmobi.rendering
53 com.inmobi.rendering.a
83 com.inmobi.rendering.mraid
29 com.inmobi.sdk
   104 com.inmobi.signals
10 com.inmobi.signals.a
13 com.inmobi.signals.activityrecognition
14 com.inmobi.signals.b
53 com.integralads.avid.library.adcolony
 2 com.integralads.avid.library.adcolony.activity
 2 com.integralads.avid.library.adcolony.base
 4 com.integralads.avid.library.adcolony.processing
 5 com.integralads.avid.library.adcolony.registration
 3 com.integralads.avid.library.adcolony.session
45 com.integralads.avid.library.adcolony.session.internal
19 com.integralads.avid.library.adcolony.session.internal.jsbridge
12 com.integralads.avid.library.adcolony.session.internal.trackingwebview
14 com.integralads.avid.library.adcolony.utils
26 com.integralads.avid.library.adcolony.video
14 com.integralads.avid.library.adcolony.walking
21 com.integralads.avid.library.adcolony.walking.async
 1 com.integralads.avid.library.adcolony.weakreference
53 com.integralads.avid.library.inmobi
 2 com.integralads.avid.library.inmobi.activity
 2 com.integralads.avid.library.inmobi.base
 4 com.integralads.avid.library.inmobi.processing
 5 com.integralads.avid.library.inmobi.registration
 3 com.integralads.avid.library.inmobi.session
45 com.integralads.avid.library.inmobi.session.internal
19 com.integralads.avid.library.inmobi.session.internal.jsbridge
12 com.integralads.avid.library.inmobi.session.internal.trackingwebview
14 com.integralads.avid.library.inmobi.utils
26 com.integralads.avid.library.inmobi.video
14 com.integralads.avid.library.inmobi.walking
21 com.integralads.avid.library.inmobi.walking.async
 1 com.integralads.avid.library.inmobi.weakreference
 2 com.ironsource.mediationsdk
   218 com.moat.analytics.mobile.inm
 2 com.moat.analytics.mobile.inm.a.b
 1 com.mobvista.msdk
 1 com.squareup.okhttp
   345 com.squareup.picasso
 6 com.startapp.a.a.a
 4 com.startapp.a.a.b
32 com.startapp.a.a.c
 7 com.startapp.a.a.d
 5 com.startapp.a.a.e
 3 com.startapp.a.a.f
13 com.startapp.a.a.g
 3 com.startapp.android.publish
 6 com.startapp.android.publish.a
45 com.startapp.android.publish.ads.a
 9 com.startapp.android.publish.ads.b
55 com.startapp.android.publish.ads.banner
87 com.startapp.android.publish.ads.banner.banner3d
35 com.startapp.android.publish.ads.banner.bannerstandard
 2 com.startapp.android.publish.ads.c.a
 5 com.startapp.android.publish.ads.c.b
   111 com.startapp.android.publish.ads.list3d
49 com.startapp.android.publish.ads.nativead
   123 com.startapp.android.publish.ads.splash
   146 com.startapp.android.publish.ads.video
12 com.startapp.android.publish.ads.video.a
31 com.startapp.android.publish.ads.video.b
48 com.startapp.android.publish.ads.video.tracking
   338 com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon
31 com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.Utils
25 com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.a
 7 com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.activities
26 com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.adListeners
90 com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.adinformation
11 com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.b
 8 com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.c
10 com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.d
48 com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.e
13 com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.f
11 com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.g
   105 com.startapp.android.publish.cache
   163 com.startapp.android.publish.common.metaData
   121 com.startapp.android.publish.common.model
17 com.startapp.android.publish.html
40 com.startapp.android.publish.inappbrowser
42 com.startapp.common
54 com.startapp.common.a
 3 com.startapp.common.b
 3 com.startapp.common.c
  1546 com.unity.purchasing
34 com.unity.purchasing.common
  1724 com.unity.purchasing.googleplay
 1 com.unity3d.ads
 1 com.unity3d.ads2
   203 com.unity3d.player
 2 com.vungle.warren
   212 com.yandex.metrica
   455 com.yandex.metrica.impl
18 com.yandex.metrica.impl.interact
   924 com.yandex.metrica.impl.ob
29 com.yandex.metrica.impl.utils
 3 com.yandex.mobile.ads
   364 for
21 for.do
26 for.do.byte
 8 for.do.case
12 for.do.char
46 for.do.do
23 for.do.for
43 for.do.if
26 for.do.int
   177 for.do.new
 1 for.do.try
63 if.do.do
 3 if.do.do.for
82 if.do.do.if
   111 if.do.do.if.do
39 if.do.do.int
71 int
   135 io.presage
47 io.presage.actions
 8 io.presage.actions.do
 6 io.presage.activities
24 io.presage.activities.do
12 io.presage.activities.handlers
73 io.presage.ads
10 io.presage.ads.controller
35 io.presage.byte
14 io.presage.case
76 io.presage.char
27 io.presage.char.do
26 io.presage.else
44 io.presage.else.do
16 io.presage.finder
56 io.presage.finder.model
14 io.presage.flatbuffers
 7 io.presage.for
47 io.presage.formats
45 io.presage.formats.multiwebviews
13 io.presage.formats.multiwebviews.video
 8 io.presage.goto
17 io.presage.helper
 8 io.presage.if
 2 io.presage.int
59 io.presage.long
22 io.presage.long.do
27 io.presage.model
15 io.presage.new
32 io.presage.provider
 9 io.presage.receiver
35 io.presage.this
20 io.presage.try
 2 java.io
15 java.lang
11 java.lang.annotation
 5 java.net
 2 java.nio
 6 java.util
 6 java.util.concurrent
 5 java.util.logging
 1 javax.xml.xpath
14 net.vrallev.android.cat
 3 net.vrallev.android.cat.instance
 1 org.apache.http.conn.ssl
20 org.fmod
 1 org.json
 8 org.nexage.sourcekit
   239 org.nexage.sourcekit.mraid
14 org.nexage.sourcekit.mraid.internal
 6 org.nexage.sourcekit.mraid.nativefeature
18 org.nexage.sourcekit.mraid.properties
36 org.nexage.sourcekit.util
40 org.nexage.sourcekit.vast
   139 org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.activity
   114 org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.model
 6 org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.processor
22 org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.view
]
stdout[
processing archive     C:\Users\ZaAz\Desktop\GameOfWords2017\GameOfWords2017\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleAIDL\libs\.\classes.jar...
processing com/android/vending/billing/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.class...
processing com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub.class...
processing     com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class...
processing archive         C:\Users\ZaAz\Desktop\GameOfWords2017\GameOfWords2017\Temp\StagingArea\android-    libraries\GooglePlay\libs\.\classes.jar...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/ActivityLauncher.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceManager.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceManager$1.class...
processing     com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceManager$1$1.class...
processing     com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceManager$1$2.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceManager$2.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceProcessor.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/Consts.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/Consts$PurchaseState.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/Consts$ResponseCode.class...
processing     com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayBillingUnAvailableException.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$1.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$2.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$3.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$4.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$5.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$6.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$7.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$Features.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IActivityLauncher.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IBillingServiceManager.class...
processing com/unity/purchasing/googlep<message truncated>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few days ago. This is your error:

```
Too many field references to fit in one dex file: 86260; max is 65536.
```

The plugins you are using all have their own dex files and the combined size, especially while using something like GooglePlayGames, can ramp up quickly.

You can bypass this by switching your build type in Build Settings from `Internal` to `Gradle`.

If you are still not able to build it correctly, you may want to consider removing some Plugins if you can. (I understand this is probably not your desired approach).

I ended up removing the GooglePlayGames Plugin, which was also slowing my build and app down.